# Define method in method call

Tags: c#

I have a class `Decision`, with Fluent interface, that I use as follows:

```
Decision.Name("MyDecision").SetRule(new MyRule());
```

Internally `Decision` has a method `Run` that calls `MyRule` `IsSatisfied` method and pass 2 arguments: `Data` and `DateType`.

I would also like to be able to use the following alternative syntax to define the Rule:

```
Decision.Name("MyDecision").SetRule((data, dataType) => {
  // Rule definition
  // Return boolean result 
});
```

How can I do this?

**Definition Class**

```
public class Definition {

  private String _name;
  private Rule rule;

  public Definition(String name) {
    _name = name;
  }

  public static Definition Name(String name) {
    return new Definition(name);
  }

  public Definition SetRule(Rule rule) {
    _rule = rule;
    return this;
  }

  public bool Run(Data data, DataType dataType) {
     return _rule.IsSatisfied(data, dataType);
  }
}
```

**Rule class**

```
public abstract class Rule {

  public abstract Boolean IsSatisfied(Data data, DataType dataType);

}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `Func<Data, DataType, bool>`?

Comment: I think the information on this question is incomplete. Are you trying to create alternate of `Run` method?

Comment: Why your rule class is abstract?

Answer (score 1):

Your are expecting to receive a `function` or a `delegate` and convert it into a `new Rule()` instance, that is an abstract class.

**The first problem is:** you can not instantiate a abstract class. So unless you add a `Type` as parameter to `SetRule` **OR** make `Rule` class not abstract. It will not be possible.

**The second problem is:** It's not a problem, but a warning. Your `Rule` class has only one method. And your `Definition` class has one one `Rule`. **If this is your real code**, it will be more clear if the `IsSatisfied` method was inside the `Definition` class.

---

But your question is: How can I do this?

```
Definition.Name("MyDecision").SetRule((data, dataType) => {
  // Rule definition
  // Return boolean result 
});
```

I'll provide an example about how to do this using `Rule` class not abstract.

First you need to make your rule class concrete an able to receive a function or an delegate in the constructor.

I'll use Func<> as Ian Kemp already provided an solution with delegate. I suggest you to use delegate for this kind of scenarios because it's better for maintainability.

```
public class Rule {

  protected Func<Data, DataType, Boolean> _isSatisfied {get; set;}

  // Deafult constructor is optional. I keep it just rise a correct type of exception in case any child class call IsSatisfied without set it first.
  public Rule()
  {
      _isSatisfied = (data, dataType) => { throw new NotImplementedException(); }; // Or any default behavior you want.
  }

  // this contructor will provide the behavior you want.
  public Rule(Func<Data, DataType, Boolean> isSatisfied)
  {
      _isSatisfied = isSatisfied;
  }

  // This method now is only a wrapper to our Func<>
  public virtual Boolean IsSatisfied(Data data, DataType dataType)
  {
      return _isSatisfied(data, dataType);
  }

}
```

Then add a new method on Definition class that receive our Func and create the rule.

```
public class Definition 
{

  private String _name;
  private Rule _rule;

  public Definition(String name) {
    _name = name;
  }

  public static Definition Name(String name) {
    return new Definition(name);
  }

  public Definition SetRule(Rule rule) {
    _rule = rule;
    return this;
  }

  // Works like a charm
  public Definition SetRule(Func<Data, DataType, Boolean> func) {
    _rule = new Rule(func);
    return this;
  }

  public bool Run(Data data, DataType dataType) {
     return _rule.IsSatisfied(data, dataType);
  }
}
```

And if you and to create a specific `Rule` that overrides and implements its own `IsSatisfied` method you can do it like this.

```
public class MyRule : Rule {

  public override Boolean IsSatisfied(Data data, DataType dataType) 
  {
      Console.WriteLine("MyRule: Dataname:{0}, DataTypeName: {1}", data.DataName, dataType.DataTypeName);
      return false;
  }

}
```

And this is an small sample:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var data = new Data() { DataName = "My Data Name" };
        var dataType = new DataType() { DataTypeName = "My Data Type Name" };

        try
        {
            // Log-> MyRule: Dataname:My Data Name1, DataTypeName: My Data Type Name
            Definition.Name("MyDecision").SetRule(new MyRule()).Run(data, dataType);

            // Log -> Func: Dataname:My Data Name1, DataTypeName: My Data Type Name
            Definition.Name("MyDecision").SetRule((dataArg, dataTypeArg) => 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Func: Dataname:{0}, DataTypeName: {1}", dataArg.DataName, dataTypeArg.DataTypeName);
                return false;
            }).Run(data, dataType);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: ", ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

You can run this sample on [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qOCR79) if you want.

If you are trying to create a generic rules engine I believe that you should give us more information about how you gonna implement your rules (On a new question).

You can also take a look on how this open sources rules engines works.

[NRules](https://github.com/NRules/NRules)

[RulesChain](https://github.com/lutticoelho/RulesChain)

Answer (score 0):

A *nondestructive* approach to achieve this is to create an extension method for `Rule` class. By the term *nondestructive* I mean an approach that does not modify the original architecture/concept of your code. In order to create an extension method, you have to first declare a `static class`. Then you have to define a method whose first parameter is pointing to the type of the target class (using `this` keyword). That said; you can implement what you need the following way:

```
public static class RuleExtensions {
    public static Boolean SetRule (this Rule rule, Func<(Definition definition, Boolean result)> definitionFn) {
       var fn = definitionFn();
       rule.SetRule(fn.definition);
       return fn.result;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a delegate typed to take in `(Data data, DataType dataType)` and return a `bool`, an internal (could also be private) class that wraps and executes that delegate, and finally a method on `Definition` to create and assign a new instance of the class.

```
public delegate bool RuleEvaluator(Data data, DataType dataType);

internal class InlineRule : Rule
{
    private RuleEvaluator _ruleEvaluator;

    public InlineRule(RuleEvaluator ruleEvaluator)
    {
        _ruleEvaluator = ruleEvaluator;
    }

    public override bool IsSatisfied(Data data, DataType dataType)
        => _ruleEvaluator(data, dataType);
}

public class Definition
{
    ... code as before...

    public Definition SetRule(RuleEvaluator ruleEvaluator)
    {
        _rule = new InlineRule(ruleEvaluator);

        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you please describe for what reason you choose definition of a delegate over simply using a `Func`?

Comment: @Transcendent It's better for maintainability. If the signature of `Rule.IsSatisfied` were ever to change, using the delegate approach I would only have to update the delegate declaration and `InlineRule.IsSatisfied`; whereas using action/func, I would have to copy-paste the new action/func declaration into every place that's currently using the delegate. I don't like copy-pasting because it's prone to errors. Secondly, it also (IMO) makes the code easier to read and therefore reason about.

Comment: That's really smart! But I still have problem with the implementation of the abstract class. How about sticking to the original implementation of `Rule` class and not creating an isotope.

Comment: @RufusL: It is, but it must have at least one implementation, and I mean that original implementation.